# TestDriven.Net doesn't find tests

Tags: .net, unit-testing, testing, mbunit, testdriven.net

I have a test project using MbUnit and TestDriven.Net.

If I right-click on an individual test method and say "Run Tests" the test runs successfully.  Same thing if I click on a file name in the solution explorer.

However, if I right click and say run tests on the project or the solution, TestDriven.Net reports "0 Passed, 0 Failed, 0 Skipped."

I have other similar projects that work just fine, and yes, the classes are labeled [TestFixture] and the methods are labeled [Test].

Comment: FWIW, I had a similar problem with NaturalSpec [http://www.navision-blog.de/2009/11/08/getting-started-with-naturalspec/] but this was b/c I was following the examples which don't tell you to use a test class but instead define the specs as variables.  I switched over to use a test class and specs as members and TD.Net was able to find the tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had once similar problem. The problem was that I forgot to declare my test class with *public* modifier.

Answer (score 4):

Are the classes public?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add testing attributes for your favorite testing framework.  TestDriven picks up these attributes by reflection in order to know what tests to run.

For example, using NUnit.Framework - each test class needs [TextFixture] and each test method needs [Test]

Here's an [example](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=test&r=2.2)

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows x64, it may be an [installer problem](http://blog.davebouwman.net/CommentView,guid,ccc158a2-d4fd-4765-9251-92be838f1ed8.aspx). It bit me on Server 20080 x64.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure TestDriven.Net was installed before Gallio, otherwise Gallio won't install its extensions for TestDriven.Net.

Gallio v3.0.4 and more recent include a 64-bit installer.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen TestDriven.Net not finding any tests if I used newest version of NUnit, reinstalling TestDriven.Net fixed the issue.